# Load external SWF correctly to main flash file as root and level0 using loadMovie() (AS2)

Tags: load, flash, actionscript-2, root

First of all sorry about my English.

I have 2 flash files,one is mine (the main container) and one is a external swf.
I want to load the external SWF to my container SWF.
I write this code in my AS2 container, inside the main timeline flash (mine flash).
In the first method, I add a movie clip with instance name `mc1` to the first layer:

```
mc1._lockroot = true;
mc1.loadMovie("external.swf");
countdown = function(){
trace("ok");
}
countdownIt = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

This code works fine in most of the cases, but I found many SWFs files that it dosen't work with.

These SWFs and work with the following code instead:

```
loadMovieNum("external.swf",0);
countdown = function(){
    trace("ok");
}
countdownIt = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

I really try to use that code - BUT !!! -> if I use this code the external SWF predominant, my main SWF code and all the rest of my code dosen't work (like the `setInterval()` timer)....

I really need help here.  I want to load the SWF like the second example and still run the `setInterval()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the original SWF when the second parameter to `loadMovieNum()` is 0.  For example, you can see both SWFs when you use this code, and the `countdown()` function still works.

```
loadMovieNum("external.swf",1);
countdown = function(){
    trace("ok");
}
countdownIt = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```